# Could not load file or assembly - After stopping then starting Azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, azure-web-app-service

I am publishing an ASP.NET MVC web application to an Azure app service.  It runs find when it is initially published.  If I turn off the app service then start it again after a few hours I get this error when I try to open the site in a browser, I can't figure out why it is working until the app is turned off then on again:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef) +36
   MyProject.Core.Plugins.PluginManager.PerformFileDeploy(FileInfo plug) +460
   MyProject.Core.Plugins.PluginManager.Initialize() +3201

 [Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   MyProject.Core.Plugins.PluginManager.Initialize() +4423

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type MyProject.Core.Plugins.PluginManager threw an exception with the following error message:     Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
.]

System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +615         System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +141
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549


[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type MyProject.Core.Plugins.PluginManager threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10075124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET     Version:4.7.3282.0
```

I see it's something to do with the `MyProject.Core.Plugins.PluginManager` assembly that is causing it.  This is a project within my solution that is used by the web application.  Sometimes when I am debugging locally and make a change to a razor page I will get an error related to this.  It's not very specific and doesn't happen consistently. I can fix in my local development environment by cleaning the solution with it happens then rebuilding.  The error I posted in this article is consistent with each time time I turn the app service off then on.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference) post talks about the specific error but it's an old post and talks about the GAC which I'm not using on Azure or in my development environment.

Comment: Maybe you could try the way in this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188166/10383250

Comment: I found the solution soon after I posted my question and I'll post the answer.  It was similar to the link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the RazorEngine version in the plugin project packages.json to the same version being used by the web project.

```
<package id="RazorEngine" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

to

```
<package id="RazorEngine" version="3.7.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Then I ran `Update-Package -Reinstall RazorEngine`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978519/assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-assembly-reference) post put me in the right direction. The comment from GeorgeChen would have helped but I found the solution before he posted.