# Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime'

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, .net-assembly

> Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Am getting this error only in IIS.

Once after installed framework 4.5 VS 2012 express i got an exception using the MachineKeyCryptography. so I uninstalled 4.5 Framework and VS 2012 due to which this mess is happening.

Any help to solve this and make my application working is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180634/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-antlr3-runtime-1-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: [I had the same issue and posted the answer in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37328091/5002554)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime (1)' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180634/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-antlr3-runtime-1-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Web Forms Application based on .NET Framework 3.5. Deleting the **bin** and **obj** directories and re-building fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time, deleting bin worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue when I upgraded my mvc4 project to mvc5. If you add the required reference file to your project references folder, it should sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

If any solutions solve your problem verify the web.config, the version of assembly. works for me

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter same issue, by entering `%TEMP%` in the File Explorer and delete all the temporary files, solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on VS 2015 and am using an MVC project. I am using impersonation for testing and am impersonating a test user created in my company's AD. After trying a lot of different solutions to this problem, I made the test user an admin on my local box, and the problem went away. Not an ideal solution, but am able to test.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to run Visual Studio as Administrator. It was apparently a permissions issue when starting debugging from Visual Studio.