# Could not load file or assembly Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I created my first MVC 4 project and it works perfectly on local server. But when I publish it on to local folder and upload the folder contents to hosting server. I try to run it and I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Can any one help me please?

Web.config:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

P.S The same project in Web Forms works on hosting server.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the .dll exists in the .bin folder of your compiled site?

Comment: Make sure you have "copy local" selected on the dll. These can be tricky errors as the dll which is in the error sometimes is not the problem "one of its dependenccies". Last resort is to install frameworks on the server.

Comment: does your host support MVC?

Comment: But when I run the same published project on local server it works!

Comment: How can I check if host support MVC?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Finally found the answer!!
Go to References --> right cilck on dll file that causing the problem --> select the properties --> check the version --> match the version in properties to web config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="YourDllFile" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"               culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-YourDllFileVersion" newVersion="YourDllFileVersion" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for until I used <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  instead of just <assemblyBinding">.

Comment: My web config already has the correct version. This didnt work for me

Comment: I had a variation of this problem and FINALLY figured it out.  My web.config looked good like this.  And project got no errors building in .NET, but got warnings during the publilsh.  I discovered TWO references to ANTLR3.Runtime inside my csproj file.  Remnant of package updates.  Took that out by editing the csproj in Notepad, and warning went away.

Comment: worked! the most logical answer for this scenario

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me immediately was:

- I located bin folder (picture below shows).
- moved all dll in other folder for safety.
- then rebuild ed the project.
- after solved the issue, deleted old dll files.

[image: Open file location]

Comment: This did the trick. I was too lazy to follow the other suggestions. This looked simpler. I think the problem was being caused due to different projects in the same solution having different versions for the same nuget package.

Answer (score 6):

If your solution contains two projects interacting with each other and both using one same reference, And if version of respective reference is different in both projects; Then also such errors occurred. Keep updating all references to latest one.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue the NuGet package version was not the same a the one on the references in the project. I had to change the version on the config to match the one in the references from the project.  Go to References --> right-click on dll file that causing the problem --> select the properties --> check the version --> match the version in properties to the web config. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Superb! this solved such an issue of mine with a project that used a dll reference I had composed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add following dll files to bin folder:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll
```

If you will not need them, delete `dependentAssemblies` from config named 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core' etc..

Comment: All of these dll files are present in bin folder.

Comment: Check dependentAssemblies in config

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Edit the *.pubxml file in the PublishProfiles folder
- set  DeleteExistingFiles `true`
- update all nugget packages, rebuild, republish and voila, issue resolved!

...worked for me when I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the project having HRESULT: 0x80131040 error is being used/referenced by any project. If yes, kindly check if these project have similar .dll being referenced and the version is the same. If they're are not of same version number, then it is causing the said error.

Answer (score 0):

I have issue with itextsharp and itextsharp.xmlworker dlls for exception-from-hresult-0x80131040 so I have removed those both dlls from references and downloaded new dlls directly from nuget packages, which resolved my issue.

May be this method can be useful to resolved the issue to other people.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the above solved it.
Web.config was like:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I added missing dependentAssembly tags and the problem solved. Probably it happened while solving a conflict. This might help someone else's problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32455265)