# Visual Studio thinks NuGet packages are installed that aren't

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, nuget, telerik-reporting

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms web site with a dependency on some Telerik packages. When I right-click on the web site in Visual Studio and "Manage NuGet Packages", the packages are listed under the "Installed" tab:

[image: Telerik NuGet packages showing as installed]

However:

1. When viewing Global.asax I get the error "Could not load file or assembly" about Telerik.ReportViewer.Html5.WebForms which seems to be breaking IntelliSense and syntax highlighting
2. The assemblies don't exist in the web site's Bin directory
3. When I try to uninstall the packages, nothing happens and they're still listed as installed

Comment: Did you build the project? "Installed" means they're mentioned in the packages.config or .csproj, but they only get copied to bin on build.

Comment: When I do a build I get the same error about not being able to load Telerik.ReportViewer.Html5.WebForms.

Comment: Did your project  based on `net framework`? Also, try to run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Conosle`.

Comment: It's not a project, it's an ASP.NET Web Site unfortunately. When I try to do a package reinstall it tells me to do a package restore, when I try to do a package restore it fails.

Comment: a website project makes this matter a little more abstract to me - in the config sense.. I see in your screenshot you have a source defined for telerik.  multible sources has been a cause of many restore failure (local feeds), as does using a combination of package.config and PackageReference in visual studio (most likely the cause).  Can you review and provide your `Options` -> `NuGet Package Manager` -> `General` settings in your question. Also, include what VS version you're using.

Comment: also, is Global.asax the only file raising this message and issue?  also, how inhibiting is the issue?

Comment: @SimonMorgan   ,could you please tell us the error message of the restore step? First, clean nuget caches, delete Bin folder, or just use [nuget xxx\xxx.sln](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-the-nugetexe-cli) to restore the packages, then rerun update-package -reinstall to test again. After that, rebuild your website project.

Comment: @SimonMorgan,Besides, please check if you have referenced such dll under web.config file. I have updated my answer. Please check it. Also, please let us know any your progress.

Comment: @SimonMorgan, please let us know if it helps or your issue still persists?

Comment: It turned out that the problem was caused by another package failing to install. It was one that I'd gotten away with not having installed before so I just ignored it but it looks like if NuGet fails to install a package, it won't even try to install any subsequent packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite a bit strange since you have installed the package `Telerik.ReportViewer.Html5.WebForms`.

Please try the following steps:

**1)** disable any third party installed vs extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

**2)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages` then rebuild your project.

**3)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then rebuild your project.

**4)** run `devenv /safemode` under **Developer Command Prompt for VS** to start a pure VS and then test your project in it.

**Besides**, when you finishing checking, please add bindredirect on your main web project.

add this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.ReportViewer.Html5.WebForms" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.1.20.618" newVersion="14.1.20.618" />
      </dependentAssembly>    
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

[Like this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32539932/12450747).

**5)** Or you could try to **create a new asp net web site project** and then install that nuget package to test whether the issue happens again.

If it still exists, please [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest version.

===========================================

**Update 1**

**clean nuget caches first**, delete `Bin` folder, or just use [nuget xxx\xxx.sln](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-the-nugetexe-cli) to restore the packages, then rerun `update-package -reinstall` to test again. After that, rebuild your website project.

Please check on your `web.config` file and make sure that you have such node:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.Html5.WebForms, Version=14.2.20.916, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=A9D7983DFCC261BE" />
      </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Make sure that you have referenced such dll in web.config.

[image]

**Then**, delete `.vs` hidden folder and `Bin` folder then rebuild your project to check whether the dll exists under **Bin** folder.

**Update 2**

=====================================================

**Finally find the reason.**

It turned out that the problem was caused by another package failing to install. It was one that I'd gotten away with not having installed before so I just ignored it but it looks like if NuGet fails to install a package, it won't even try to install any subsequent packages.

Comment: Also, you could update `Progress Control Panel for Windows` under `https://www.telerik.com/account/` to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this thread, just wanted to add that simply running `update-package -reinstall` fixed the issue for me. I was having issues, maybe because I have many projects referencing the same Nuget packages.

1. Tools
2. Nuget Package Manager
3. Package Manager Console
4. Paste:

`update-package -reinstall`

5. Press Enter