# Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' in production

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `MVC 5` application and get Could not load file or assembly `'Antlr3.Runtime'` or one of its dependencies.

> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When we publish to production server. Everything works great in local machine. Someone have any ideas?

I have try to empty temp folders in booth `%temp%` and `Framework64 och` Framework Temprory files. But its not working.

Comment: is your app pool set to 32/64 bit?

Comment: Check the runtime version of the application pool...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime (1)' or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180634/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-antlr3-runtime-1-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Comment: I use v4.0 version. i have try both 32 and 64 bit with same result.

Comment: Does your MVC application reference other projects?  If so, do any of those projects use that assembly?

Comment: Apparently deleting your `%TEMP%` folder contents can fix it.

Comment: I recall this happening to me in the past.  I believe my nuget packages got messed up.  Try uninstalling any nuget packages you have.  Then reinstall them.