# After Computer crash VS 2013 is not loading 'Antlr3.Runtime' assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

My computer crashed while building code in VS2013.  After restart when i run my code without debugging it runs fine but when in debug mode, I got the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = Antlr3.Runtime
>    (Partial)
>   WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
>   WRN: Assembly Name: Antlr3.Runtime | Domain ID: 2
>   WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
>   WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
>   WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
>   WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
>   WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/qqq/qqq.Admin/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\qqq\qqq.Admin\bin
>
> ## Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\qqq\qqq.Admin\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\DevBatch\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/051d9c22/9e0bcfb5/Antlr3.Runtime.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/051d9c22/9e0bcfb5/Antlr3.Runtime/Antlr3.Runtime.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/qqq/qqq.Admin/bin/Antlr3.Runtime.DLL.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\qqq\qqq.Admin\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\DevBatch\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.3.1.7705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070057). Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.3.1.7705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
>      System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.3.1.7705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.3.1.7705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9931916
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

I have did my R&D and the closest solution i got is to delete all files from

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\

And also clear these

> C:/Users[username]/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/

Plus i have reloaded 'Antlr3.Runtime' dll But no luck so far.

Comment: have you tried deleting files in `Framework` too? (not `Framework64`)

Comment: yes i have deleted all files ..

Comment: Even i have updated my Antlr3.Runtime dll, DotNetOpenAuth.aspnet dll and EntityFramework dll via nuget package but no luck so far

Answer (score 3):

I'm struggling with this problem and after 2 hours searching and trying, I found a simple solution here.

1. Delete all files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\
2. Delete all files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\
3. Clear C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/ (if any).
4. **Delete all files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only solution for you here, is to create a new project, run it in debug (to make sure it is working) and then copy all of your project to the newly created one (You can try using tfs for merging in order to save time).

The thing is, that once the studio is crushing, it is ruined because this specific `Antlr3.Runtime`, is getting mixed as well and cannot recreate itself. This is an issue to be aware of.

Comment: I have tried this also .. and still the same issue.. even i updated my respective dll via nuget package but no luck so far !!!

Comment: Then one last thing to do, uninstall the visual studio and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually copy that file (Antlr3.Runtime.dll) to your bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

**[Please refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180634/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-antlr3-runtime-1-or-one-of-its-dependencies)**

> Enter %TEMP% in the File Explorer and delete all the temporary files.

.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before, the best thing to do is to clear your temp folder and delete all the files in the bin folder of the project. Clean Solution and Rebuild, Tadang! you are good to go :) Hope this helps someone come here looking for an answer in the future.