# ASP.NET MVC & MEF - Pluggable architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, modular-design

I started creating a PoC following SO [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21037036/310276) but I wasn't able to get a very basic sample to work.

What I did:

- I created an ASP.NET MVC project using empty template and MVC references.
- I added `Bootstrapper`, `CustomControllerFactory` and `CustomViewEngine` classes and also the corresponding lines in `Application_Start`.
- I created an ASP.NET MVC project using MVC template.
- I added the `Export` and `PartCreationPolicy` decorators on `HomeController`.
- I published the module project to a folder inside /Modules directory -in `WebHost` root path.

What didn't work:

- The method `CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue` throws an exception saying that it couldn't load one or more required types and that there is more information on `LoaderExceptions` property. That property is an array with 77 instances of what appears to be the same exception:

  > `Could not load file or assembly Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.4.1.9004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f or one of its dependencies.`
  >   In `FusionLog` property I can see that the problem is related to the assembly version ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13297402/310276)).
- I found a workaround for "solving" this by copying the `dependentAssembly` declarations from the module's `web.config` to the `WebHost` configuration file. However I'd like to avoid this as the `WebHost` should not be modified based on the module's needs.
- Even after the workaround, it didn't work. While rendering the view, it threw this exception:

  > `CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Sounds like you need a way for plugins to contain their necessary dependencies

Answer (score 0):

For your help is share a full test project using MEF. visit this [github](https://github.com/ashiquzzaman/MEFMVC) link.

You need something like--

```
public class AzRDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

        public AzRDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called to request a service implementation.
        /// 
        /// Here we call upon MEF to instantiate implementations of dependencies.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceType">Type of service requested.</param>
        /// <returns>Service implementation or null.</returns>
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");

            var name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);
            var export = _container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<object>(name);
            return export;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called to request service implementations.
        /// 
        /// Here we call upon MEF to instantiate implementations of dependencies.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceType">Type of service requested.</param>
        /// <returns>Service implementations.</returns>
        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");

            var exports = _container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
            return exports;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, we should avoid using IDependencyResolver. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22058942/310276